# Is it good practice to define a getter which does not return a specific field?

Tags: java, getter

a kind of simple question. Are methods like this good practice?

```
private NavigableMap<Double, Site> m_sites;

private Site getRandomSite()
{
    return m_sites.ceilingEntry(Math.random()).getValue();
}
```

Or is it bad because it is a getter and you could expect that it would return the field "randomSite"?

Comment: I would rather generate the random number outside, and pass it to this method. And let this method just get the `Site` for the passed number.

Comment: @RohitJain Ok, but then the method would be called something like "getCellingSite". The question is if it is good or ok to have methods starting with "get" and not returning a specific field

Comment: And it's sad to see that (the `m_sites` for those reading me, since I deleted my comment).

Comment: @CalibeR Of course. No issues in that. As long as your method name makes sense, and is in sync with what it does, there shouldn't be any issue with it.

Comment: @NoDataFound the m_ is a company's code convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is fine, although I can understand that you wouldn't want to call it `getRandomSite()` because it looks like a getter method. Building on Gio's answer, I suggest you call the method `fetchRandomSite()` because as you said, this method does not generate the random site, it simply picks (or fetches) it out of a NavigableMap.

Answer (score 3):

If you, the author of the code, think it is confusing / bad with respect to the rest of your code base, than change the name to for example `generateRandomNumber()`. However, there is no convention which says that a "get method" must always return a field.

Comment: my actual source code is a little bit different. It gets a random entry out of a NavigableMap using cellingEntry. I can't use "generate" for this. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2):

A getter can get anything in back (return anything). Doesn't mean that it return only some field's value. No issues with your current method.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is bad practice. Methods like that should be static, and encapsulated in utility classes, as they have nothing to suggest that they are associated with the enclosing class. In addition, the utility class should have a private constructor so it cannot be accidentally instantiated.

A situation where they **may** be useful is as MyClass.allocateNextUniqueKey(). But in this case the method should not allocate an already used key, so it most definitely has an association with MyClass.

Comment: Caveat: The question has been edited since I answered.

Answer (score 0):

If your method does compute something, then probably a method name that explicits this behavior is better:

```
private NavigableMap<Double, Site> m_sites;

private Site pickRandomSite()
{
    return m_sites.ceilingEntry(Math.random()).getValue();
}
```

In any case, whether it's a real getter (that is a dummy method for the lacks of properties like in C# or the fear of public fields for `struct` equivalent) or not, the only thing that matters is that the method name reflects its purpose.

Example: don't call `getSite()` a method that would return a random site.

On a side note, what bugs me - more than the use of `getRandomSite` - is the `m_sites`. I know after asking that this is a company convention, but it's like obfuscation to me (I hate *the prefix member/method by its scope* naming convention).

Answer (score 0):

There are some conventions regarding getters. If there is a getter, there may be a corresponding setter. This setter must take one parameter with exactly the same type as the getter. Some Frameworks e.g. Spring may enforce this.

Back to your Question, it is expected that getters return a field at last. This doesnt mean that the field must be directly returned. There may be e.g. lazy-loading or conversion (getDurationInMillis, getDurationInSeconds,...), but is it really expected that get-Methods return the same value if no change is done. Math.random() seems to be a prime example for this. It is called random() instead of getRandom() because changing values are returned.

In conclusion, if a method doesnt fulfill all getter-expectations, it is probably better to name it otherwise. fetch, search, ...